# ray tracing | diffused shading with multiple light sources creates weird shadows at 90 degrees

Tags: c++, raytracing, shading

I am having problems with my implementation of diffused shading in the ray tracing project I recently started.

You can clearly see some dark lines along the spheres wherever the light hits it at an angle of 90 degrees. The turquoise sphere is the one where you can see it best.
[image: example image]

[image: example image]

I have no idea where this is coming from... My code for the calculation of the brightness looks like this:

```
float brightness = 0;
for (Light* light : unintersectedLights)
{
    Vector3 intersectionToLightDirVec = Vector3Normalize(Vector3Subtract(light->position, intersection));
    float angleBetweenNormalAndLight = Vector3AngleBetween(intersectionNormalVec, intersectionToLightDirVec);
    brightness += Clamp(Remap(angleBetweenNormalAndLight, 0, PI / 2, 1, 0), 0, 1) * light->brightness;
}

color = ColorMultiply(color, brightness);
```

First I thought it looked like one of the values was negative which can't be since I clamped the results and I also double checked it and there was never a negative value.

Now I'm stuck with these dark lines and I am not sure if I should just continue or if this would be a problem with future calculations too.

Here's the complete code: https://github.com/vequa/RayTracing3D

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: I've not done 3D computer graphics calculations for a long long time, but I think Vector3AngleBetween should normalize the vectors first then do the dot product. Then again I could be completely wrong, but it looks like you're running into a numerical instability (1/very big number) or (1/very small number).

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes you are right and I will change it right now but in this case ntersectionNormalVec and intersectionToLightDirVec are already normalized Vectors so this is not the problem

Comment: `angleBetweenNormalAndLight  = abs(...` will make negative angles (surfaces facing away from the light) positive. Remove the `abs` should give you the correct result. You can also use it as an early out to avoid the following computations.

Comment: @Bert I just tried this and while I thought the abs was needed, it actually didn't do anything but sadly it also had nothing to do with the dark lines.

Comment: What does `Remap` do with a value outside of its mapping range? The 2nd picture you posted looks like what you get when you ignore the direction of the light, i.e., it looks like you are illuminating surfaces facing away from the light. Are you sure your normals are correct as well? I also don't understand why you make such a complicated scene. Placeing a single sphere at the origin and a light above it, might make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: @Bert Remap will just scale everything outside of its mapping range the same way as it does with everything else e.g. Remap(25, 0, 50, 0, 100) = 50 and Remap(150, 0, 50, 0, 100) = 300... because of this I also thought the abs was necessary since 40deg and -40deg are the same in case of difference to 0deg but would get a different result after Remap.
I am pretty sure my normals are correct since everything works as it should as long as the angle to the light isn't about 90deg.
Also the second and the first picture are produced by exactly the same code just the number of lights is different.